# Creating a destructor for a template class(2d dynamic) that has many friend functions c++

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, dynamic, destructor

i'm having problems creating a destructor for a template class that has a private 2d dynamic array. for some reason the destructor destroys the matrix as soon as i am done entering information into the matrix. not sure what went wrong since it compiles fine but gives an error when i enter the info for the first 2 matrices and the program tries to multiply them. the code works if i get rid of the destructor.

```
template <class T>
class matrix
{
//sudo
friend matrix operator + , *,-,(bunch of friends used to overload)
//end sudo 
public:
                matrix(): rows(0), cols(0){}
                int Arows(){return rows;}
                int Acols(){return cols;}
            class Proxy
            {
                matrix& _a;
                int _i;
            public:
                Proxy(matrix& a, int i) : _a(a), _i(i){}
                int& operator[](int j) {return _a.Array[_i][j];};
            };
                Proxy operator[](int i) {return Proxy(*this,i);}
                ~matrix();
                private:
                T ** Array;
                int rows;
                int cols;
                };

                template<class T>
                matrix<T>::~matrix()
            {
                for (int i=0;i<rows;i++)
                    delete [] Array[i];
                delete [] Array;
            }
```

Comment: See [the rule of three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) and [the rule of zero](http://rmartinho.github.com/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html).

Comment: thanks reading both of them now

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell without seeing the exact code and calling code, but it might be because you are missing copy constructor and assignment operator.

```
matrix m1;    
{
 matrix m2 = ...
 m1 = m2; // copy ctor, now they share same Array pointer
} // m2 destructor free the Array

// m1 is left with dangling Array pointer
```

from the code sample it doesn't seem like real code. Where is Array initialized, what is matrixArray?